# USB-C dock audio output causes crashes

Tags: debian, audio, dock-station

I have a Lenovo **Thinkpad X1 Nano** Gen 1 (20UN) running **Debian 12** (6.1.0-16). It is connected to a Lenovo **Thinkpad USB-C Dock** Gen 2 (40AS). Everything runs fine except the audio output.

**When I select the 3.5mm audio jack on the docking station as audio output device, software that outputs audio immediately crashes**. For example, if I go to Settings; Sound; select the Analog Output of the Dock as output; and do the trusty "front left, front right" test, the whole Settings application crashes without any audio being played (Settings is not responding -> Force quit). The same happens if I want to play a song through Spotify.

The integrated speakers and audio jack of the laptop work fine. Also, if I run Ubuntu in a KVM, it can play sound over the analog output on the docking station just fine as well!

I don't really know what to do here... Does anybody have an idea? Is there any package or setting that I can copy over from Ubuntu to get it to work on Debian also?

Thank you!